# How to conceptualize and calculate the variance in the waiting time?

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to calculate the mean and variance in the waiting time for the following situation:

You are at the grocery store waiting to check out.  There are 100 people in the line, and 10 cashiers. Each person takes on average 'n' minutes, with a variance of 'v'.

The mean seems straightforward: 10 * n.  I feel like the variance should be v/10, but I'm not sure.

I'd really appreciate a mathematically rigorous solution and explanation.

Thanks!